# jQuery help for slideshow: adding a div for box-shadow effects has jQuery selecting the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, addclass, box-shadow

So I used [this place](http://jonraasch.com/blog/a-simple-jquery-slideshow) to help me create a slideshow, however, thanks to certain limits of CSS, you can't set a box-shadow property to IMG.

However, the issue is thanks to the nature of the script, once it's done running through the IMGs, it encounters the div.

The script is not supposed to encounter the div as the div is only used for decoration (again, since box-shadow can't be used for IMG). I was hoping someone would be able to help me with the formating of the code so as to ignore the #slideshadow div.

HTML (edited with replacement pictures, thanks to CSS, the dimensions were necessary):

```
<div id="slideshow">
  <img class="active" src="http://i.imgur.com/pPPkQDZ.jpg" alt="" />
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Axp8aGT.jpg" alt="" />
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/UMpQ9eh.jpg" alt="" />
<div id="slideshadow">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#slideshadow {
    position: absolute;
    height:455px;
    width: 750px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 80px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    border-top-left-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
    border-left: 5px groove #990000;
    z-index: 15;
}

#slideshow {
    position:relative;
    height:455px;
    width: 750px;
    float: left;
}

#slideshow IMG {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:8;
    opacity:0.0;
    border-top-left-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
    border-left: 5px groove #990000;
}

#slideshow IMG.active {
    z-index:10;
    opacity:1.0;
}

#slideshow IMG.last-active {
    z-index:9;
}
```

SCRIPT:

```
function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

    if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');

    var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
        : $('#slideshow IMG:first');

    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
}

$(function() {
    setInterval(slideSwitch, 3000 );
});
```

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: The script is not supposed to encounter the div as the div is only used for decoration (since box-shadow can't be used for IMG). I was hoping someone would be able to guide to formating the code so as to ignore the #slideshadow div.

Comment: You can do like this `var $next =  $active.next('img').length ? $active.next('img'): $('#slideshow IMG:first');`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a specific element inside `.next()`.

```
function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

    if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');

    var $next = $active.next('img').length ? $active.next('img'): $('#slideshow IMG:first');

    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
         .addClass('active')
         .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
         });
}

$(function() {
    setInterval(slideSwitch, 3000 );
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it! I'm a novice with Java/jQuery currently. However I work best by dissecting working code. I'll run this through a diff checker and see what edits you made, though I think I immediately see it.. and am batting my forehead.

Comment: Glad to help :) I guess you mean javascript/jquery as java and javascript are not same. I have changed only one line where I am asking `.next()` to only match sibling `img` tags. Before `.next()` would return all siblings i.e `img and div`