# Javascript/CSS slideshow: Using transparencies highlights flaws I don't know how to fix

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As much as I'd love to have this be as broad as possible to help future coders, this is a rather specific problem.

As you can see in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lam6fo3f/2/), this slideshow seems to have an issue with pictures with transparencies. With transparencies, there is a fairly jarring transition. If possible, I'd like to have the old picture fade out as the new picture is fading in.

And a note: the slideshadow div is there for a reason, mainly for box-shadow uses with greater control over z-index.

HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow">
   <img class="active" src="http://i.imgur.com/tqMy9wn.png" alt="" />
   <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vNyEFB0.png" alt="" />
   <div id="slideshadow">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#slideshow {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    height:245px;
    width:200px;
}

#slideshow IMG {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:8;
    opacity:0.0;
}

#slideshow IMG.active {
    z-index:10;
    opacity:1.0;
}

#slideshow IMG.last-active {
    z-index:9;
}

#slideshadow {
    position:absolute;
    height:245px;
    width:200px;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 80px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    z-index:15;
}
```

JS:

```
  function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

    if ($active.length == 0) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');

    var $next = $active.next('img').length ? $active.next('img') : $('#slideshow IMG:first');

    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({
        opacity: 0.0
    })
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({
        opacity: 1.0
    }, 2000, function () {
        $active.removeClass('active last-active');
    });
}

$(function () {
    setInterval(slideSwitch, 7000);
});
```

Comment: Why do you use $ in front of your js variables, like if this was php? I am curious.

Comment: If I knew why, I'd tell you. It was code offered by a website, that has been refined to my uses. I'm still learning Javascript. The way I tend to learn is I take examples and try to dissect each part to discern its function.

However, I do believe $ is a jquery thing.

Comment: But that query thing has nothing to do with variables, AFAIK.

Comment: AHA! I found the source material: http://jonraasch.com/blog/a-simple-jquery-slideshow Perhaps your answer can be found there?

However, I'd refined it to my uses after this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29606294/jquery-help-for-slideshow-adding-a-div-for-box-shadow-effects-has-jquery-select (my own question which resulted in the slideshadow div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an explicit fade to transparent seems to work:

```
$active.animate({
    opacity: 0.0
}, 2000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tbyccesq/